# how can I mock the Context using Mockito and Robolectric?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, robolectric

This is a snippet of my activity :

```
public class Search extends Activity
{
    private String TAG = "SEARCH";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);
        Log.d(TAG, "About to call initialastion");
   //        new InitialisationTask(this).execute();
    }
}
```

With the line above commented, I can happily create and execute unit tests like so :

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class SearchTest {
    private Search searchActivity;
    private Button searchButton;
    private Button clearButton;
    private Button loginButton;
    private Button registerButton;
    private EditText searchEditText;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        searchActivity = new Search();
        searchActivity.onCreate(null);

        searchButton = (Button) searchActivity.findViewById(R.id.btnPlateSearch);
        clearButton = (Button) searchActivity.findViewById(R.id.btnClearSearch);
        loginButton = (Button) searchActivity.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        registerButton = (Button) searchActivity.findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        searchEditText = (EditText) searchActivity.findViewById(R.id.editTextInputPlate);
    }


    @Test
    public void assertSearchButtonHasCorrectLabel()
    {
        assertThat((String) searchButton.getText(), equalTo("Search"));
    }
}
```

However, if I uncomment the line `new InitialisationTask(this).execute();` in my activity, my tests start to fail, most likely because of the reference to `this`.

What is the best approach for mocking the context?

I have tried to add `contextMock = mock(Context.class);` into my `setUp()` however I'm not sure how I can set this mock "into" the `searchActivity`

Thanks

Comment: Can you share code of your task?

Answer (score 13):

For robolectric 3.0, to get the Context object you simply use:

```
RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext();
```

In your code above, you don't have to explicitly create the activity object and call it's onCreate() method. Robolectric can setup activity for you using:

```
searchActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(SearchTest.class);
```

Answer (score 5):

For getting the Context of the Activity or Application you can use :

```
Robolectric.getShadowApplication().getApplicationContext();
```

For Example :

```
Context context = Robolectric.getShadowApplication().getApplicationContext();
```

Now use the context variable.

Comment: Note this is an answer for Robolectric 2.x and older.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Robolectric 3.2. This is what I used:

`ShadowApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext();`